# Weekly sum using google sheets using a single formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[Make a copy of gsheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fQK3jQiZ1tJpLJ00euWa-KbdFn7UVU9f0xss9E3pDe4/edit?usp=sharing)

I need to find the weekly sum of B col for every week and PLACED IN LAST DAY OF WEEK
Which means (dark colored cells) would get sum of B cells for the week

All days arent listed and hence we may need to detect the end of week day for placing total

[image]

I would like to have a arrayformula in L1 cell or L2 cell or lambda map since I dont want to drag down formulas and cells

I tried with `=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIFS(B:B, E:E, "<>" & E2:E, ROW(D:D), "<=" & ROW(D:D)))`

The expected values are written in L3 and L10 for first samples

Answer (score 1):

*Here's one approach you may test out:*

```js
=let(Σ, scan(,A2:A,lambda(a,c,ifs(c="",,weeknum(c)=iferror(weeknum(offset(c,-1,))),a+offset(c,,1),1,offset(c,,1)))),
     map(A2:A,Σ,lambda(Λ,Γ,if(weeknum(Λ)<>iferror(weeknum(offset(Λ,1,))),Γ,))))
```

[image]

Comment: How can I adapt to change this formula if B placed in K column?

Comment: A small explaination would be really helpful